# java- how to obtain name field in name-value pairs stored in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to parse a hashmap that contains name-value pairs...

The entities stored in the hashmap are words with a numerical value corresponding to each word.

This is the code that I am using:

```
hMap = (HashMap) untypedResult;

/*
    get Collection of values contained in HashMap using
    Collection values() method of HashMap class
*/
c = hMap.values();

//obtain an Iterator for Collection
Iterator itr = c.iterator();

//iterate through HashMap values iterator
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    resp.getWriter().println(" Value= " + itr.next());
    //resp.getWriter().println(" To String of iterator= " + itr.toString());
}
```

I am able to obtain the numerical values associated with each word using the above code. How do I obtain the value of each word as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
c = hMap.values();
```

If you want the keys as well, you shouldn't call `values()`. Call `entrySet()` instead:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : hMap.entrySet()) {
    resp.getWriter().println("Key " + entry.getKey()
                             + "; value " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Or for the raw type (ick):

```
for (Object rawEntry : hMap.entrySet()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) rawEntry;
    resp.getWriter().println("Key " + entry.getKey()
                             + "; value " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but for the first line itself ( for (Map.Entry..................) I am getting this error- Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry<String,Integer>. Kindly advise on what is causing this error. Thank you.

Comment: @Arvind: It's probably due to using the raw types. Editing the second form... but if at all possible, using a generic type properly would be better. Even `HashMap<?, ?>` would be better than `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Either with #keySet or #entriesSet

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html